# "Sensor outputs" or "sensors' outputs"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence, expression-choice, saxon-genitive

I acquire measurements from several sensors, and I need to filter these signals. Is there a difference between the two sentences below?

The sensors' outputs are filtered.
The sensor outputs are filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first sentence, sensor's outputs just says 'outputs belonging to the sensors'. It sounds unwieldy every time you read it. 
The second sentence helps establish 'sensor outputs' as a term by itself, which would be useful if you were using it repeatedly later on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

*The sensors' outputs are filtered* probably means that the output of each sensor is individually filtered.

*The sensor outputs are filtered* can be taken to mean that the outputs are combined in some way before being filtered.